# c# WinForms DataBinding doesn't update my TextBox.text

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I wanna bind a TextBox to a class property, so when this property changes, my TextBox changes automatically too (Windows Forms).
I have a class like this:

```
class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string can_rpm;
    public string Can_rpm
    {
       get { return can_rpm; }
       set { can_rpm = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    
    \\lots of other codes
}
```

My main form has some code like this (with a textbox called 'tbTest'):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Device device= device = new Device();
   tbTest.DataBindings.Clear();
   tbTest.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",device,"Can_rpm",true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
   
   \\lots of other stuff         
}
```

My problem: My textBox never updates! A have some other code that updates the 'Can_rpm' property, but nothing shows on my textbox.text. BUT, if I change the empty value of my textbox to something else, my property DOES change too!
So it's working 'one way', but not the other!

I've searched here and googled it, but all I find is examples that does what is already done in my code, but mine doesn't work.

Thanks for helping if you can.

Comment: What is this declaration: `Device device= device = new Device();` meant to achieve? Did you also declare a Field of Type Device somewhere else? Are you trying to reflect the change of a Property value of this Field in the TextBox? That is a local variable -- Try instead `private Device device = null;` (<- Field declaration), then in the event handler: `device = new Device(); [...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
tbTest.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), device, nameof(Device.Can_rpm));
```

I've tested the code with your `Device` class code and this code in the form constructor:

```
var device = new Device();

this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), device, nameof(Device.Can_rpm));
        
device.Can_rpm = "Hello";
```

After that, my textbox has "Hello" text.

**UPDATE**

You need update controls always in the thread in which they was created, usually in the main thread. I use a Form extension methods to do that:

```
public static class FormExtends
{
    public static void RunInMyThread(this Form form, Action operation)
    {
        if (form.InvokeRequired)
        {
            form.BeginInvoke(operation);
        }
        else
        {
            operation();
        }
    }
}
```

With the previous extension, you can do (in your Form code) your updates in this way:

```
this.RunInMyThread(() => device.Can_rpm = "Hello");
```

Another way to do that:

```
public class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static SynchronizationContext GuiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    private string can_rpm;
    public string Can_rpm
    {
        get { return can_rpm; }
        set { can_rpm = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            GuiContext.Post(
                s => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)), 
                null);
        }
    }
}
```

`GuiContext` is initialized in the main thread so it runs the code in that thread. If you change your `PropertyChanged` event to throw in the `Post` of that context, you don't need take care about where your device properties are changed because the notiy always run in the main thread.

Comment: Victor, I've tried that way but it didn't work....

Comment: jimi, that was a typo. My class Device has a global instance called 'device'. I wanna see this global instance property when it changes

Comment: My code works, I've tested. Can you provide a more complete example that fails? The problem must be in other part, not in the binding.

Comment: Victor, I've found what's going on! My example did work here, BUT, im my 'real software', there's another thread that updates the value of my 'device' class.
So I did the same in this example: I've created a button which creates a Thread, and this thread just changes the value of my property, and it stops refreshing my Textbox! 
So I guess the problem is something like cross-thread with UI, but I don't know how to fix it cuz I do need another thread to update my class properties.

Comment: In the window "Properties" there's a field called (DataBindings). I could configure the dataBinding through there, BUT it seems that it takes the class itself, instead of the instance I'm gonna create. Is there a way, in this window and NOT in code, for me to bind my data to some instance of the class? Cuz my class is not static (and could not be)

Comment: Maybe your static "device" makes collision with the device local variable?